# How do You Build an RSS feed with Jade?

Tags: pug

I'm building my own front-end framework with Jade, and I was wondering if there is a way to build an RSS feed file that will get updated automatically on every compile.

Is there a way to automatically create something like a JSON file with objects that contain page information that can be fetched in a Jade loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Yes to all !!! you can do that. I will give an example to follow.

In the nodejs

```
app.all('/myCool.:name(rss|xml)', function(req, res){
    res.type('xml'); // <-- Type of the file
    // myFeeds is a Array!!
    res.render(req.params.name, { myFeeds : myFeeds, url : req.originalUrl });
});
```

In RSS `rss`

```
doctype xml
rss( version="2.0", xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/", xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' )
    channel
        title My Cool feed
        link= url
        //- I use momentjs
        lastBuildDate= moment().toUTCString()

        docs http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/tech/rs
        generator My Nodejs Generator Feeds for RSS
        each feed, i in myFeeds
            item
                title= feed.title
                guid( isPermaLink="true" )= feed.id

                updated= feed.date.toUTCString()
```

In Atom `xml`

```
doctype xml
feed( xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom', xml:lang='es')

    link( href= url, rel='self' )
    //- I use momentjs
    updated= moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ")
    title My Cool feed
    author
        name AlejoNext
        uri https://alejonext.co
    generator My Nodejs Generator Feeds for Atom

    each feed, i in myFeeds
        entry
            title!= feed.title
            id= feed.id
            updated= moment(feed.date).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ")
```

It is an excellent way to generate content, you can render any kind of `xml` in jade.